# Variable Argument Lists in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, syntax, c++-cli, arguments, variadic-functions

How do I create a function which accepts a variable argument list in C++/CLI? I am looking to create a function which forwards most of it's arguments to `String::Format`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Declare the last argument as a managed array prefixed with an ellipsis.

Here is a variable argument function that just passes all of its arguments to String::Format

```
String ^FormatAString(String ^format, ...array<Object^> ^args)
{
  return String::Format(format, args);
}
```

And here is how to call it:

```
Console::WriteLine(FormatAString(L"{0} {1} {2}.", 40.5, "hello", DateTime::Now));
```

Comment: Concise, with a simple example that does compile: this is a near perfect answer.